# How to avoid orphaned frame titles in beamer article?

Tags: beamerarticle

I use `\usepackage{beamerarticle}` to turn my beamer slides into lecture notes. However, I get many orphaned frame titles, i.e. frame titles that appear at the end of a page, with the frame contents appearing on the next page. Is there a way to keep frame titles with the frame contents?

Comment: Suggestion: include a MWE and people are more likely to help.